# select value sibling with condition

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements, siblings

I have an xsl to select values from documents which works fine but I need to add a condition to it and can't figure out how.
The source xml has a recurring node like this:

```
<recurringNode><field1>1000</field1><field2>valueA</field2></recurringNode>
```

To select the value of the field2 based on the value of the field1 I use this instruction nd it works fine:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//field1[text()='ABC']/following-sibling::field2/text()"/>
```

But I need to enhance it. I need to add an OR condition to check the value in the field1. The condition would be:

field1 = 'ABC' or substring(field1, 0, 1)='X'

Is it possible to achieve it?

Regards.

JT

Comment: `substring(field1, 0, 1)='X'` That will never be true. The `substring()` function counts from 1, not 0.

Comment: I know, it counts from 1 for 1 position, but it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="recurringNode[field1='ABC' or starts-with(field1,'X')]/field2"/>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful description. You can see that it does work here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsP

Comment: Now I see your point, thanks. Your solution is quite different from my first approach but it does provide an answer for what I asked. I have to rephrase the question. Let's say I have a couple of fields, namely field1 and field2, I need the value of field2 based on what I find in field1. I know these fields are always in pairs within a recurring node which we don't know the name for. That's why in the xsl instruction I first posted, you don't see the name of the father/recurring node. Your solution is based on the recurring node name, I need to do it with my first approach, is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it is rather awkward: `<xsl:value-of select=".//field1[.='ABC' or starts-with(.,'X')]/following-sibling::field2"/>`. Why not simply replace the name of the recurring node with the * wildcard?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed :) Thank you very much.